# Split command in HBase shell

Tags: hbase, cloudera-cdh, ycsb

I am trying to run ycsb on HBase with CDH ycsb parcel. I am following Cloudera's blog [ycsb-the-open-standard-for-nosql-benchmarking-joins-cloudera-labs](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/ycsb-the-open-standard-for-nosql-benchmarking-joins-cloudera-labs/) . In this blog, I see the below command,

```
hbase(main):001:0> n_splits = 200 # HBase recommends (10 * number of regionservers)
```

`hbase(main):002:0> create 'usertable', 'cf', {SPLITS => (1..n_splits).map {|i| "user#{1000+i*(9999-1000)/n_splits}"}}`.

what does this `{SPLITS => (1..n_splits).map {|i| "user#{1000+i*(9999-1000)/n_splits}"}`mean?
I understand that this is being used for splitting the regions. But I am unable to find what the above command actually doing? Please help me to understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

It is a ruby thing as stated here http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#shell

> The Apache HBase Shell is (J)Ruby's IRB with some HBase particular commands added. Anything you can do in IRB, you should be able to do in the HBase Shell.

So you first declare a split number variable

```
hbase(main):001:0> n_splits = 200 # HBase recommends (10 * number of regionservers)
```

Then use ruby syntax to generate an array as SPLITS parameter of 'create' command

```
hbase(main):002:0> create 'usertable', 'cf', {SPLITS => (1..n_splits).map {|i| "user#{1000+i*(9999-1000)/n_splits}"}}
```

Even the command 'create' itself is a ruby function. you can find definitions at $HBASE_HOME/lib/ruby/shell/commands

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, the command is pre-splitting the table in regions. That is recommended for YCSB because the performance test loads a lot of data that would land in a single region server and would end up in a poor evaluation as data wouldn't be distributed across the cluster.

The ideal number of splits depends on other factors. I'm unsure why they chose that formula but I'm guessing it is because of the workload examples.

You can also run the command on a [Ruby online tool](https://repl.it/repls/TestyDarkorangeFact) and check the results yourself:

```
user1044
user1089
user1134
user1179
...
user9999
```